# how to embed jw flash player in asp c# page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, flash, jwplayer

I want to play flv files on my web page using jw player, can any one suggest me how to embed and set path of url.

i has download jw player files such as player.swf,swfobject.js & jwplayer.js
my code is here:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="VideoPlayer.aspx.cs" Inherits="VideoPlayer" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHead" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceBody" Runat="Server">
  <table class="style14">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='/jwplayer/jwplayer.js'></script>

            <div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
        'flashplayer': '/jwplayer/player.swf',
        'file': 'Baby.FLV',
        'controlbar': 'bottom',
        'width': '470',
        'height': '320'
    });
</script>
            </td>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Did anything work for you..??

Comment: not working can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
<div id="container">Loading the player ...</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">  
    jwplayer("container").setup({  
        flashplayer: "/jwplayer/player.swf",  
        file: "/uploads/Baby.FLV",  //change to where ever the path is for your example
        height: 470,  
        width: 320  
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried but didn't got.   <script type='text/javascript' src='/jwplayer/jwplayer.js'></script>

            <div id="container">Loading the player ...</div>  

            <script type="text/javascript">  
            jwplayer("container").setup({  
                flashplayer: "/jwplayer/player.swf",
                file: "/Video/Prety baby dance.FLV",  //change to where ever the path is for your example
                height: 470,  
                width: 320  
            });  
            </script>

Comment: it's working now. i have did wrong in flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf", //slash(/) no need to write.